# Add primary key to existing sql table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, primary-key

In a table with columns ID, Name and Qualifications I am trying to make ID my primary key, but I get an error.

```
import sqlite3 as SQLite
try:
  objConexionSQLite = SQLite.connect('Escuela_Preparatoria_21_Sánchez_Conde_Eric_Sebastián_Semestre_2024_1.db')
  print("\nConectado a la base de datos")
except:
  print("Error durante la creación de la base de datos")

Table.to_sql("Base de Datos - Calificaciones Examen 01", objConexionSQLite, if_exists="replace",index=False)
print('Tabla creada con éxito\n\n\n')

with objConexionSQLite as con:
  con.execute('''ALTER TABLE `Base de Datos - Calificaciones Examen 01` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);''')
```

I get

```
OperationalError: near "PRIMARY": syntax error
```

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html _SQLite supports a limited subset of ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE command in SQLite allows these alterations of an existing table: it can be renamed; a column can be renamed; a column can be added to it; or a column can be dropped from it._

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT;
```